# Accessing a set state value inside a typography component with MUI

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm using react state to set error messages based on specific user input issues. I want to display the correct error message at the bottom of my form on submit. The issue I'm having now is how to pass the state error message to my Typography element so that when the users inputs invalid data, the correct error message is thrown.
here is where I set the error messages:

```
const [error, setError] = useState('');

if (email === '' || password === '') {
            setError('Sign in attempt failed');
            setSubmitted(false);
        } else if (!verifyPassword.test(password) || !validated) {
            setError('Please complete all fields to log in');
            setSubmitted(false);
        }
```

and my const where I'm trying to put my error message in the Typography component:

```
 const errorMessage = () => {
        return (
            <div
                className="error"
                style={{
                    display: error ? '' : 'none',
                }}
            >
                <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ m: 1 }} color="red">
                    // This is where I want to set the error message to return.
                </Typography>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution to this but it's escaping me at present. Any input or suggestions is welcome. Thanks

Comment: `const errorMessage = ({msg})=> { return <Typography>{msg}</Typography>}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you correct, your error state variable can go inside {mustaches} inside your Typography component.

```
 <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ m: 1 }} color="red">
        {error}
 </Typography>
```

additionally, you might consider rendering nothing if the error is falsey, rather than hiding it using styles. something like this:

```
const errorMessage = () => {
    return ({ error ? 
        <div className="error">
            <Typography variant="h6" sx={{ m: 1 }} color="red">
                // This is where I want to set the error message to return.
            </Typography>
        </div> : ''}
    );
};
```

Most of the time, you can do away with showing and hiding, and use conditionals to decide what does and doesn't render.